Rust generic type bounds that allow any reference type (shared or mutable) that implements a trait while maintaining reference characteristics
Is there a way I can write my_function so I can pass in any value that implements MyTrait and then be able to pass it into multiple child function calls?
struct MyType1;
struct MyType2;

trait MyTrait<'a> {}

impl<'a> MyTrait<'a> for &MyType1 {}
impl<'a> MyTrait<'a> for &mut MyType2 {}

fn my_function<'a, T: 'a>(x: &'a T)
where
    &'a T: MyTrait<'a>,
{
    some_library_function(x);
    some_library_function(x);
}

fn some_library_function<'a>(x: impl MyTrait<'a>) {}

fn main() {
    let foo = MyType1;
    let mut bar = MyType2;
    my_function(&foo);
    // expected `&MyType1`, found `&mut MyType2`
    my_function(&mut bar);
}

Some things I've tried and their outcomes:
If my_function declares T: MyTrait, I can only call some_library_function once because x is moved.
Saying that &'a T: MyTrait<'a> allows me to call some_library_function multiple times however my_function then only supports implementations that are shared references, i.e. &MyType1, not mutable references, i.e. &mut MyType2 in my example.

To clarify, can you control the function signature (argument type) of some_library_function or must it be impl MyTrait<'a>?

The library function is in a third party crate that is out of my control.

Providing a link to that crate/function would increase the chance of a useful answer :)

Shared references are easy: because they are Copy, you can just require Copy:
struct MyType1;
struct MyType2;

trait MyTrait {}

impl MyTrait for &MyType1 {}
impl MyTrait for &mut MyType2 {}

fn my_function<T>(x: T)
where
    T: MyTrait + Copy,
{
    some_library_function(x);
    some_library_function(x);
}

fn some_library_function(x: impl MyTrait) {}

But you also want to support mutable references, and this is where things turn more complicated.
See, mutable references are not Copy. They cannot be - if I would able to copy mutable references, I could very easily create aliasing references, and from here the path to unsoundness is real short. But still, they have the illusion of being Copy. When I have a mutable references, I can move it many times - how?
The secret is reborrows. When you move a mutable reference, the compiler doesn't actually move it - instead, it reborrows it, an operation that can be explicitly written as &mut *reference. A reborrow is an operation of the form <'a: 'b, 'b> &'b mut &'a mut T -> &'b mut T. That is, you borrow a (long) mutable reference for a short time. The reference becomes unusable for that (short) time, but in exchange, you get a new mutable reference that is valid for the short time.
This works when the compiler knows there is a mutable reference, but doesn't work with generics. We can simulate it, but it won't be as convenient:
struct MyType1;
struct MyType2;

trait MyTrait<'a> {
    type ShorterRef<'b>: MyTrait<'b>
    where
        Self: 'b;
    fn reborrow<'b>(&'b mut self) -> Self::ShorterRef<'b>;
}

impl<'a> MyTrait<'a> for &'a MyType1 {
    type ShorterRef<'b> = &'b MyType1
    where
        Self: 'b;
    fn reborrow<'b>(&'b mut self) -> Self::ShorterRef<'b> {
        *self
    }
}
impl<'a> MyTrait<'a> for &'a mut MyType2 {
    type ShorterRef<'b> = &'b mut MyType2
    where
        Self: 'b;
    fn reborrow<'b>(&'b mut self) -> Self::ShorterRef<'b> {
        *self
    }
}

fn my_function<'a, T>(mut x: T)
where
    T: MyTrait<'a>,
{
    some_library_function(x.reborrow());
    some_library_function(x);
}

fn some_library_function<'a>(x: impl MyTrait<'a>) {}

fn main() {
    let foo = MyType1;
    let mut bar = MyType2;
    my_function(&foo);
    // expected `&MyType1`, found `&mut MyType2`
    my_function(&mut bar);
}


I didn't have it in the question, but MyTrait is actually owned by the third party crate.  Is it possible to write a generic wrapper trait that can be implemented generically for the shared reference and mutable reference types?  Worst case I could implement it specifically for the two types I'm interested in.

@sWW Yes, it is possible.
